# Authorization Header in Swift POST

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlrequest, urlrequest

My app creates POST request with Authorization header - it looks like :

```
let accessToken = "veryCoolToken"
var request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
request.httpMethod = "POST" 
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("token=\"\(accessToken)\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I already checked this request with Postman app - it was fine. But for some reason I received needed result only from Postman and not from my app.

So after taking apart request on my Server - I found that when my app sending POST request - it is not "**A**uthorization" but "**a**uthorization".

Why is that happening?

What else should I take in consideration when app sends POST request with headers?

Comment: You should change your backend to accept case insensitive headers. HTTP headers in iOS are case insensitive to conform to [HTTP RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html).

Comment: So when I write "Authorization" - iOS device sends "authorization" and it is fine?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

For POST requests in Swift, generally you have to set the following:

```
request.setValue("Basic " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the reason why of my issue?

Comment: All POST requests for basic authentication have authorisation headers in this format in swift. You could try replacing the `token=...` line with this to test it out.

Comment: I have problem not with value of Authorization header. I have problem with "Authorization" sended in lowercase variant

Comment: Directly setting the `Authorization` is not recommended, as it is a reserved header within iOS. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest