make an HTTP request with Authentication type Bearer Token in Swift
I have to call api with Authentication type  Bearer Token. There is no parameter available. in my code the httpMethod: .post asking for any Encodable.
screen shot from post man 
 private func getUserData(accessToken: String) async throws -> UserInfoData {
        let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "Token": accessToken,
        ]
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let urlString = Resource.baseURL(for: .accessToken)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString),
                let encoded = try? encoder.encode(parameters) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        
        let request = Request<UserInfoData>(
            url: url,
            httpMethod: .post(
                encoded
            ),
            parameters: nil
        )
        return try await service.fetch(request: request)
    }
}

Can any one  help to make the api call?

""Token": accessToken," That's not usually the way you need to put the token, it's usually  in the header field. Ask Postman to Generate cURL or Swift code you'll how it's done.

This bearer thing usually used as Authorization: Bearer eyJh...

can I write
request.setValue( "Bearer (accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
inside the post method what should I pass?

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391849/7916438, I'd write request.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"). Assuming that accessToken is the eyJ... string. However, if you happen to be on iOS, see the comment and link after that post, there may be some extra hoops ahead.
